# Multiple Export of Different Selections in Dropdown selection

Tags: google-sheets, automation, autohotkey

I'm trying to find a way to automatically change the dropdown to the next name on the list, wait for a second or so for the results below to change and then export that page as PDF!

I would do it manually but there will be about 100 names on the list!

The data pulls up fine it's just the avoiding all the manual work that would be done each month for the 100 people!

And maybe if there's a way to rename the pdf with the name of the person?

Too Much?

I[image: Example Of Sheet With Dropdown]

Comment: Is this something like generating a monthly performance report? Presumably the existing delay is because the name is chosen from a dropdown, so all the data on the screen has to refresh. But if you designed a separate sheet for reports, you might not (or not) have the delay (which you might manage with `flush` anyway). Would you please share your spreadsheet (remove any private or confidential info, or chnage the names to protect the innocent) so that we can see/experiement with the raw data.

Comment: "and then export that page as PDF" Would you clarify what you understand by "export"? "And maybe if there's a way to rename the pdf with the name of the person?" Yep, that ought to almost be the easiest bit.

Comment: Export, or download, my bad, I just wanted a pdf copy of the sheet in question!

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a script ?
You could first get all the item of your drop down list, then you change the cell value of your drop down list and you pause the script for 1 second.
If you need more help to do it just ask me !

Comment: I wonder whether this should be considered an answer. It contains the kind of information one might find in a comment. But I don't see how the questioner could read this answer and be better informed about "how" to resolve their problem.

Comment: I cannot comment on an another user post (I don't have enough reputation). And my answer provide what to do, but I don't know the OP programming skills,

Comment: Fair point to the reply! Thanks! The issue I found was the recording macro in Google ignored the download as pdf functions. Unless I make a download as pdf link for the page and have that on a separate sheet, then flip back to the drop down in the macro.... Hmmmmm that's clunky but functional!

Answer (score 0):

this is not really resolvable in the scope of Google Sheets only. basically what you need is a macro that will run outside of the box and automate whole this process while you take a quick nap. you should look into [**AutoHotKey**](https://www.autohotkey.com/) which is able to do exactly what you want with delays, auto clicking on buttons to download and stuff like that. there is full documentation on how to build your script, many tutorials and even discord channel if you need pro help. Example:

- **https://youtu.be/bS-ycdoOyj8**

Comment: Thank you @player0 I'll have a look at this as a semi automatic resolution! This would be actually do the job well enough!  Thanks for the help!